# Referring back to code in C#

Tags: c#, back, goto

Is it was possible to run a console application in c# which has the ability to go back to a area of code?

More details --

**Application launch:**

*start code*

runs thought code

*Goes back to start*

I know this can be done in batch with marking an area with `:test1` then `goto test1` will return

Comment: perhaps a loop would work.

Comment: *goto* is available in c# too :)

Comment: Not sure that will be best for what im trying to do.

Comment: And what are you trying to do?

Comment: I couldnt find anything on goto for c#

Comment: @JoshuaHodson, see the link in my answer.

Comment: Post some code showing what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Perhaps you should study a bit the keywords of the language and what they do before.

Comment: never use `goto` for looping. we have loop! you can use `for` `foreach` `while` and `do while`

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a loop, or you somewhat partially answered your own question in that you could use the [goto keyword.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend you use a loop. Your options are: do...while, for, or while. Any of them would work depending on what basis you want to loop on.

Simplest case you want to never end:

```
while(true){
...
}
```

Comment: Don't forget foreach. Of course depending on what he is looping exactly...